# Set cursor focus on TextField when form load in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, textfield

I have 3 textfields (Username, Password, Confirm Password). When the form loads I wish for the cursor to start off in the textfield Username when the form is first displayed. Please give me some advice. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 29):

`[usernameTextField becomeFirstResponder];`

This should provide you with the desired result. You can read about the [responder chain here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html) if you want to understand more about the mechanism.

Edit:

My bad, I thought you meant UITextField (Cocoa Touch).

> Use the NSWindow makeFirstResponder: method, not this method, to make
>   an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.

```
[window makeFirstResponder:usernameTextField];
```

Comment: Is your text field properly connected in the Interface builder?

Comment: yes it already connect. I declare in .h (IBOutlet NSTextField *txtUsername; and synthesize in .m (@synthesize txtUsername) and then I drag the connector but it still not work.

Comment: I don't believe this will make much of a difference but have you set the `UITextField delegate`?

Comment: I develop on Mac application I use NSTextField

Comment: Old post, but this worked perfectly for me with a NSTextField. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the message `becomeFirstResponder`, like so:

```
[self.passwordField becomeFirstResponder]
```

Answer (score 2):

[yourTextfield becomeFirstResponder]

Answer (score 1):

In your `loadView` or `viewDidLoad` (which is available in 10.10 only) add the following after `super` call

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    [self.usernameInputField becomeFirstResponder];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to achieve this in a NSPanel (or any other sheet) and you disable the title+border, the focus cannot be set (see http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/207749-nstextfield-will-not-become-editable-in-borderless-window.html)

In that case, try to subclass the sheet window class and override canBecomeKeyWindow to always return YES.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift

self.sampleUITextField.becomeFirstResponder()

Answer (score -1):

For macOS, using Swift 3, the becomeFirstResponder() call has to be in the viewWillAppear() method.

```
class myViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: NSTextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear {
    myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
  }
  ...
}
```